# react-native-pdf-view - How to populate pdfView with blobId

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the react-native-pdf-view library and I am having trouble populating the PDFView with a pdf.
in the response, I don't get any path or URL just the blobId that I have to display in the app.

response:

> _data:
> blobId: "D354BA37-14F4-48BC-A091-FF02BC291C7F"
> name: "ABC02_A_20190421_0900_0000001.001"
> offset: 0
> size: 1424202
> type: "application/pdf"

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for react-native-pdf [github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf#types-of-sourceuri](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf#types-of-sourceuri) you can find content types and one of them is {uri:"blob:xxxxxxxx-...?offset=0&size=xxx"} - load pdf from blob URL You just need to prepare your URL properly